# Train test dataset regression results

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, statsmodels

My problem is that I am applying a simple linear regression on my data: when I split the data to train and test data I don't find significant model when bad p-value and r squared and adjusted r squared results while there is good results in train data. 
Here's the code for more explanations :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm
from scipy import stats
data = pd.read_excel ("C:\\Users\\AchourAh\\Desktop\\PL14_IPC_03_09_2018_SP_Level.xlsx",'Sheet1') #Import Excel file
data1 = data.fillna(0) #Replace null values of the whole dataset with 0
print(data1)
X = data1.iloc[0:len(data1),5].values.reshape(-1, 1) #Extract the column of the COPCOR SP we are going to check its impact
Y = data1.iloc[0:len(data1),6].values.reshape(-1, 1) #Extract the column of the PAUS SP
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size =0.3,  random_state = 0)
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train, Y_train)
plt.scatter(X_train, Y_train, color = 'red')
plt.plot(X_train, regressor.predict(X_train), color = 'blue')
plt.title('SP00114585')
plt.xlabel('COP COR Quantity')
plt.ylabel('PAUS Quantity')
plt.show()
plt.scatter(X_test, Y_test, color = 'red')
plt.plot(X_train, regressor.predict(X_train), color = 'blue')
plt.title('SP00114585')
plt.xlabel('COP COR Quantity')
plt.ylabel('PAUS Quantity')
plt.show()
X2 = sm.add_constant(X_train)
est = sm.OLS(Y_train, X2)
est2 = est.fit()
print(est2.summary())
X3 = sm.add_constant(X_test)
est3 = sm.OLS(Y_test, X3)
est4 = est3.fit()
print(est4.summary())
```

At the end, when trying to display statistical results, I always find good results in train data but not in test data. Probably something wrong in my code.
To notice I am a beginner with python

Comment: Give a minimal example that can reproduce your problem will make other help you easily and quickly

Comment: maybe it's because you're fitting to a test set which is much smaller than the training set...

Comment: but data is composed of 26 lines 19 lines go for train data and the rest for test data

Comment: so just 7 lines for fitting `est3`? clearly the results will be much worse than when fitting to 19 lines for `est`. imagine fitting to just 1 line each (extreme case). is it any wonder the adj. r squared values etc. are terrible?

Comment: yes exactly all the values are terrible the p-value the adjusted rsquare. what should I do ? stop the train test thing or just split 50 for train and 50 for test

Answer (score 0):

Try running this model a few times, without specifying `random_state` in `train_test_split` or changing the `test_size` parameter.

I.e.

`X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size =0.2)`

As of now, every time you run the model, you do **the same** split of data, so it is possible that you overfit the model just because of the split.

Comment: yes did what you told but either the train or test data have no significance results when splitting the data while when I do a full analysis of the data I find a good significant values

Comment: then it seems like sample size matters: have a look here [small sample p-value](http://allenfleishmanbiostatistics.com/Articles/2012/01/13-p-values-in-small-samples/)